# Symfony 3: Resize image on upload

Tags: php, symfony, image-uploading

I need to resize images on upload and cant really find my way around it.
I'm not using any bundles for this and I followed the [UploadFile](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html) example from symfony documentation.

This is working, copying the image in the right folder but I need to resize it somehow.
I need some some way to do it without adding a bundle, if possible.

This is the service (just like in documentation):

```
class ImgUpload
{
    private $targetDir;

    public function __construct($targetDir)
    {
        $this->targetDir = $targetDir;
    }

    public function upload(UploadedFile $file)
    {
        $file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();

        empty($file_name) ? $file_name = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension() : $file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();

        $file->move($this->targetDir, $file_name);

        return $file_name;
    }
}
```

And this is in my controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("admin/import_images", name="import_images")
 */
public function importImgAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(ImportImgType::class, NULL);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $paths = $form->get('path')->getData();

        foreach($paths as $path) {
            $this->get('app.img_upload')->upload($path);

        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('product_list'));
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle:productmanager:import_images.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Marius, looking at your previous questions I would strongly encourage you to read [What topics can I ask on StackOverflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), because "`I need some code`" is Off-Topic here! However your question it's also too broad and there are million ways to implement this. Start looking the [Liip Imagine Bundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle).

Comment: Hey, thank you for your suggestion! I was getting frustrated because I did read the How to ask and I keep getting bad review to all my questions and I'm not sure why. I guess I should choose better words :).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an entity listener that listens for persist and update of the entity you update using your ImportImgType and if there is a new image, resizes.

```yaml
app.entity_listener.resize_img:
  class: AppBundle\ResizeImgListener
  tags:
    - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener, entity: AppBundle\Entity\ImportImg, event: postUpdate }
    - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener, entity: AppBundle\Entity\ImportImg, event: postPersist }
```

For more details on entity listeners: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners-class